# How to declare observables or computed properties in Ember using ES6?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ecmascript-6

Trying to use ES6 for all of my Ember work. I have the following ES6 syntax issue:

How do I convert standard ES5 object literal computed property to ES6 syntax?

**ES5:**

```
 export default Ember.Controller.extend({
     foo: function() {
         return "bar";
     }.property()
    });
```

**ES6:**

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  foo() {
    return "bar"
}.property()
});
```

What I have so far does not seem to work because .property is not referenced correctly. How is this achieved?

Comment: Maybe you can use them without the prototype extension?http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/#toc_functions

Comment: @altrim I also noticed using the inline methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ES6 only supports that syntax when inside of a class. I'm not sure Ember exposes its class system in a way that works with standard JavaScript.

I highly recommend not using the prototype extensions. That is, you would always do this:

```
foo: Ember.computed('bar', function() {
  return this.get('bar');
})
```

It reads much better to me.

Comment: Notice that the method syntax works in object literals just as well, not only in classes.

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to work with Ember 1.13:

```
export default class extends Ember.Controller {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);

    this.foo = Ember.computed('bar', function() {
      return this.get('bar');
    });
  }
}
```

Notice the "export default class" and the slightly annoying aspect of defining your functions inside the constructor.

You could also split the function definition:

```
export default class extends Ember.Controller {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);

    this.foo = Ember.computed('bar', this.foo);
  }

  foo() {
    return this.get('bar');
  }
}
```

But then you have the downside of splitting the computed nature of the function with the function itself.

Would love to hear other ideas if people have them as I much prefer the ES6 style of defining classes.

Answer (score 0):

With the new getter syntax:

```
foo: Ember.computed('bar', {
  get() {
    return this.get('bar');
  }
})
```